# Results surprising said lab reporter of emission testing on Toyota Qualis Diesel 4 wheeler on AVL DiTest MDS 205

Tags: toyota, diesel, emissions, testing, efficiency

I got emissions of Toyota Qualis Diesel car tested with the AVL DiTest MDS 205, the result sheet had following columns rpm, temp, secs, CO(%vol.), CO corrected, CO2(% vol.), HC(ppm),HC corrected(ppm),Dilution, O2(%vol.), Lambda, NOx(ppm), AFR. I am mentioning 3 readings with low, medium and high rpm, accordingly. The person testing it said the results are a bit surprising, are they good? are they bad ? He didn't say, I wanted to understand what these readings mean, and if they are actually so different from a generic diesel engine car.

1)Time=29sec, RPM=660,Temp=80C,CO corr.(%vol)=0.06%, CO2(%vol.)=2.54, HC 
corr.=18ppm,Dilution = 5.9,O2(%vol.)=16.88, lambda=5.648, NO(ppm)=102, AFR=83.1

2)Time=14sec, RPM=1800,Temp=87C,CO corr.(%vol)=0.06%, CO2(%vol.)=2.46, HC 
corr.=18ppm,Dilution = 6.1,O2(%vol.)=17.1, lambda=5.861, NO(ppm)=51, AFR=86.2

3)Time=18sec, RPM=2720,Temp=82C,CO corr.(%vol)=0.09%, CO2(%vol.)=3.46, HC 
corr.=9ppm, Dilution = 4.3,O2(%vol.)=15.74, lambda=4.176, NO(ppm)=48, AFR=61.4

Comment: I think you'll have better luck getting answers on a diesel specific forum.

Comment: I tagged 'Diesel' in the post, do you know any diesel specific forums?

Comment: Googling 'Toyota qualis forum' turned up this site: http://www.team-bhp.com/forum/indian-car-scene/68484-toyota-qualis-product-review-discussion.html

Comment: @MooseLucifer Yes its a car Toyota sells in India. But I don't think there are any experts on this issue on those forums, thats why I turned to stackExchange. Thank you for your suggestion though, I'll put up the same question there too.